# How to use and import a Modal in react native?

Tags: react-native, modalpopupextender

I have a simple modal in a file, and I want to import it to use in the App.js.
Don't know how to do the process to get it up and running in the App.js

```
import {} from 'react';
import modal...
const modal = props =>{
  
   return(
       <Modal>
         ...
       </Modal>
   );
}
export default modal;
```

In the App.js do not know how to do!

Answer (score 0):

just import from location. then use with brackets